# ¿Cómo filtrar un array de objetos que tiene dentro un array?

Tags: javascript, filtro

Como filtrar un array con varios objetos que dentro tiene un array?
El objeto viene así:

```
const miArray = [
  { id: 1, nombre: "obj1", edad: 22, colores: ["rojo", "verde", "blanco"] }, 
  { id: 2, nombre: "obj2", edad: 30, colores: ["azul", "verde", "morado"] }, 
  { id: 3, nombre: "obj3", edad: 22, colores: ["naranja", "amarillo", "negro"] }, 
  { id: 4, nombre: "obj4", edad: 51, colores: ["negro", "verde", "rosa"] } 
]
```

Yo se que si quisiera filtrar este array en un nuevo array tendría que ser así:

```
var arrFiltered = newArr.filter((el) => el.edad === 22)
```

Y arrFiltered traería los dos objetos que tienen edad de 22, pero si quisiera hacer esto con los colores, como podría filtrar dependiendo de cada uno de los colores que vienen en ese array dentro de cada obj, por ejemplo si quisiera tener a todos los objetos que tienen "verde" en un nuevo array, sobre todo teniendo en cuenta que no conozco la extensión de cada array de colores, puede tener n cantidad de colores

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacerlo primero haciendo un `filter()` para que te devuelva todos los objetos que cumplan con la condición y luego un `find()` para buscar el color **verde** dentro del array **colores** de cada objeto.

```js
const miArray = [
  { id: 1, nombre: "obj1", edad: 22, colores: ["rojo", "verde", "blanco"] }, 
  { id: 2, nombre: "obj2", edad: 30, colores: ["azul", "verde", "morado"] }, 
  { id: 3, nombre: "obj3", edad: 22, colores: ["naranja", "amarillo", "negro"] }, 
  { id: 4, nombre: "obj4", edad: 51, colores: ["negro", "verde", "rosa"] } 
]
const nuevoArray = miArray.filter(
  (elemento) => elemento.colores.find((color) => color === 'verde')
)

console.log(nuevoArray)
```

**Referencias:** [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te sirva, agregando metodo **includes** dentro del metodo **filter** podras buscar por el color que requiera

```js
 const miArray = [
            { id: 1, nombre: "obj1", edad: 22, colores: ["rojo", "verde", "blanco"] },
            { id: 2, nombre: "obj2", edad: 30, colores: ["azul", "verde", "morado"] },
            { id: 3, nombre: "obj3", edad: 22, colores: ["naranja", "amarillo", "negro"] },
            { id: 4, nombre: "obj4", edad: 51, colores: ["negro", "verde", "rosa"] }
          ]

          var arrFiltered = miArray.filter((el) => el.colores.includes("amarillo"));

          console.log(arrFiltered);
```